# Dynamic conditional formatting help required for Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight when the same invoice number has been used by the same provider

I can highlight duplicate invoice numbers easily using this formula:
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B,B2)>1
I can't quite get the formula right using "AND" to look at column A to check if the duplicates are being used by the same provider..

So for example, I would like only B3 and B15 to turn orange

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPQq8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first request try the following formula and apply it in range `B2:B`

```
=INDEX((COUNTIF($A$2:$A&$B$2:$B,A2&B2)>1)*(A2:A<>""))
```